# Bootstrap карусель

Tags: bootstrap, carousel

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему карусель не работает?(((
Не работает анимация , смена слайда по нажатию на стрелочки навигации....
Уже минут 40 парюсь, не понимаю((

```html
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/dopstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<!-- Карусель -->

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Индикаторы для карусели -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <!-- Перейти к 0 слайду карусели с помощью соответствующего индекса data-slide-to="0" -->
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <!-- Перейти к 1 слайду карусели с помощью соответствующего индекса data-slide-to="1" -->
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <!-- Перейти к 2 слайду карусели с помощью соответствующего индекса data-slide-to="2" -->
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>   
  <!-- Слайды карусели -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <!-- Слайды создаются с помощью контейнера с классом item, внутри которого помещается содержимое слайда -->
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="arbolit">
      <h2>Arbolit</h2>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Заголовок 1 слайда</h3>
        <p>Текст (описание) 1 слайда...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Слайд №2 -->
    <div class="item">
    <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="arbolit">
      <h2>Slide 2</h2>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Second slide label</h3>
        <p>Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis gravida odio.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Слайд №3 -->
    <div class="item">
    <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="arbolit">
      <h2>Slide 3</h2>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Third slide label</h3>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Навигация для карусели -->
  <!-- Кнопка, осуществляющая переход на предыдущий слайд с помощью атрибута data-slide="prev" -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <!-- Кнопка, осуществляющая переход на следующий слайд с помощью атрибута data-slide="next" -->
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: bootstrap.js - подключили?

Comment: @soledar10    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
 <link href="css/dopstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
и всё равно не перелистывает (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте bootstrap.js. проверьте пути к js/css файлам.

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <link href="css/dopstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<!-- Карусель -->

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Индикаторы для карусели -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <!-- Перейти к 0 слайду карусели с помощью соответствующего индекса data-slide-to="0" -->
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <!-- Перейти к 1 слайду карусели с помощью соответствующего индекса data-slide-to="1" -->
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <!-- Перейти к 2 слайду карусели с помощью соответствующего индекса data-slide-to="2" -->
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>   
  <!-- Слайды карусели -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <!-- Слайды создаются с помощью контейнера с классом item, внутри которого помещается содержимое слайда -->
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="arbolit">
      <h2>Arbolit</h2>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Заголовок 1 слайда</h3>
        <p>Текст (описание) 1 слайда...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Слайд №2 -->
    <div class="item">
    <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="arbolit">
      <h2>Slide 2</h2>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Second slide label</h3>
        <p>Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis gravida odio.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Слайд №3 -->
    <div class="item">
    <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="arbolit">
      <h2>Slide 3</h2>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Third slide label</h3>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Навигация для карусели -->
  <!-- Кнопка, осуществляющая переход на предыдущий слайд с помощью атрибута data-slide="prev" -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <!-- Кнопка, осуществляющая переход на следующий слайд с помощью атрибута data-slide="next" -->
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: была ошибка в подключении. Не думал, что она окажется такой тупой эта ошибка( спасибо вам